# Filter common elements of two arrays with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have these two states that consist in two arrays.

```
const bundle = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: "schedule",
    action: "skip",
    target_action: "reset"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: "schedule",
    action: "reset",
    target_action: "skip"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    type: "check",
    action: "reset",
    target_action: "skip"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: "check",
    action: "skip",
    target_action: "reset"
  }
];

const active = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: "schedule",
    isActive: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: "schedule",
    isActive: false
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    type: "check",
    isActive: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: "check",
    isActive: false
  }
];
```

When items in **active** turns inactive (isActive: false) by clicking a button, they get filtered out of the array.

```
const handleActive = (item) => {
    setActive((prevState) => {
      
      const existingItem = prevState.find(
        (activeItem) =>
          activeItem.id === bundleItem.id &&
          activeItem.type === bundleItem.type,
      );
      if (!existingItem) {
        return [...active, { ...bundleItem, isActive: true }];
      }

      return prevState
        .map((oldItem) => {
          return oldItem.id === existingItem.id &&
            oldItem.type === bundleItem.type
            ? { ...existingItem, isActive: !oldItem.isActive }
            : oldItem;
        })
        .filter((itemToFilter) => itemToFilter.isActive);
    });
  };
```

Basically, I want to implement a useEffect that dynamically updates **bundle** in two ways simultaneously:

1. items must have at least one of **action** or **c_action** keys
2. when **active** gets updated (some elements get inactive and filtered out), I want to keep only the common items between the two arrays (same ID and type)

I implemented these two effects.
The first one to filter out the inactive elements from bundle:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setBundle((prevState) => {
      return bundle.filter((bundleItem) =>
        active.some(
          (activeItem) =>
            activeItem.id === bundleItem.id &&
            activeItem.type === bundleItem.type,
        ),
      );
    })
  }, [active]);
```

The other one to filter out from bundle elements that doesn't "action" or "c_action" key.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setBundle((prevState) => {
      return bundle.filter(
        (bundleItem) => bundleItem.action || bundleItem.c_action
      );
    });
  }, [bundle]);
```

The second useEffect I implemented throws an infinite loop: bundle gets endlessly updated.

Thanks, a lot.

Comment: You haven't identified what is not working as expected in the code shown or provided a question. You need to tell others where you specifically need help

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to clutter the question with other code. Now I add some info, you're right.

Comment: So the higher level problem is the infinite loop then? If so that would be a better lead in to this whole question

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you're looking for is actually an `useMemo` use case

you can do something like

```js
const filteredBundle = useMemo(()=> bundle.filter(
        (bundleItem) => bundleItem.action || bundleItem.c_action
      ),[bundle]);
```

And use the filtered bundle where makes sense